# Dynamic item insertion messing up the zebra striping

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, ujs

I have a simple list of products where zebra striping is achieved using the `cycle` method.

**Here is the product partial:**

```
<tr class="product <%= cycle 'odd', 'even' %>">
  <td><%= product.name %></td>
  <td><%= product.price %></td>
  <td><%= product.percentage %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Show", product %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(product), :remote => true %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Destroy", product, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote => true %></td>
</tr>
```

However, when I dynamically insert another product, the cycle method logically picks the first class (in this case the "odd" class) thus breaking the striping until the next reload. Although dynamically reloading the entire product would work; this method seems somewhat dirty and would likely mess with the pagination. Since I'm still relatively new to JavaScript and Prototype I'm unable to come up with this on my own so I have to ask: Is there a way to get the class of the previous product ("odd" or "even") and add class to the newly inserted product accordingly?

**My current UJS used to insert the partial:**

```
Modalbox.hide();

function insertProduct() {
   $('products').insert( { top: "<%= escape_javascript(render @product) %>" } );
   $$('.product').first().highlight(); 
}

insertProduct.delay(0.8);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't seen "UJS" used in a while. Modern libraries are all built on it's ideal but many have forgotten about the "Unobtrusive" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionut Staicu is essentially right but has forgotten it's Prototype. Final answer should be;

```
$$('.product').invoke('removeClassName', 'odd')
              .invoke('removeClassName', 'even')
              .first().highlight(); 
$$('.product:even').invoke('addClassName', 'even');
$$('.product:odd').invoke('addClassName', 'odd');
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Only small issue: when you create two records right after each other, the top three products all get the 'even' class added.

Comment: Is it because I put `.first().highlight()` in the middle of instructions? I did that as a shorthand but might work better last. I don't know how `highlight()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

After you insert elements, you need to remove all class `odd` and `even`:

```
$('tr.product').removeClass('odd even');
```

Then you need to add classes again:

```
$('tr.product:even').addClass('even');
$('tr.product:odd').addClass('odd');
```

so the code will be like this:

```
[...]
$$('.product').first().highlight(); 
$('tr.product').removeClass('odd even');
$('tr.product:even').addClass('even');
$('tr.product:odd').addClass('odd');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, I do it like this:

```
$('#product-<%= @product.id %> ~ .product').each(function(index) {
  $(this).toggleClass('odd');
  $(this).toggleClass('even');
});
```

The selector says: find product with id "product-XX", then for every following element that has a class product, toggle class odd and even (remove it if it's present, and add it if it's not).

Comment: How can you be sure the newly added element will be given the correct class? If there were an even number of items before the new row will be odd, then toggled to even, when it is placed at the top of the list. Also since you've chosen to answer in jQuery you don't need the `each` loop, just use `$('#...').toggleClass('odd').toggleClass('even')`

Answer (score 0):

Were I doing this and if I could rely on each row being a fixed height I would probably use a striped background image instead. That doesn't allow for differing foreground colours or any CSS property than a background. Still, it would be very reliable.